# Wordpress: How to add query arg on click

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently building a site which lists apartments for rent. I have created a custom post type with several custom fields associated with it. Right now I have one page that list all of my custom posts and th query looks like this:

```
<?php 
// args
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'lejlighed'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
```

I want to add/alter the query when a user is clicking on a link or checking a checkbox. I have tried this by using the add_query_arg function, but without success:

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'post_nr','6500' ); ?>"> 6500 </a>
```

"post_nr" is the meta key and "6500" is the meta value.

The idea is that the user is able to filter the list of apartments by custom fields like zip code. Ideally I would like to load new content without page refresh, but that is a different matter.

So my question how would I go about adding arguments to the query by clicking on an element?

Answer (score 1):

You could try loading all the available posts and filter them using JavaScript. This would require you to apply filtering data to each post (e.g. an attribute called `data-zipcode` or `data-postnr`) and then create the filtering buttons (or similar) that are used to determine which types of posts to display and when.

Another option is to create an script that does post loading (and would either return HTML or JSON), then AJAX embed it every time a user clicks on a filter. This would happen by generating an AJAX request to your post loader script which in turn would output the correct posts into your main template (the AJAX request would pass WP_Query arguments to your post loader script).

The first option is a bit heavier up-front, but the second option requires some bandwidth on each request. Depending on the amount of posts you need to be able to show initially you'll need to decide which one is the better way to go.

Comment: I have to admit I relatively new to ajax and javascript. I don't really have a clue where to start, even though your comment should point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in a bit of a rush right now, I'll see if I can manage to edit in a few examples later today. Checkout `admin-ajax.php` related documentation at the WP Codex, there's some pointers on AJAX in WordPress (the right way).